# Improvement on my Dijkstras Implementation?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am currently learning the popular algorithms in preparation for job interviews. Can someone tell me if my implementation can be improved on? I know that you can use a binary heap/priority queue to improve the Time Complexity to O(E+Vlog(V)) and that my implementation is O(V^2), but other than that, would this be sufficient or should I try to learn it in a more 'pythonic' manner?

```
g = {
'A':[{'D':2}, {'C':1}],
'B':[{'C':2}, {'F':3}],
'C':[{'A':1}, {'D':1}, {'B':2}, {'E':3}],
'D':[{'C':1}, {'G':1}],
'E':[{'C':3}, {'F':2}],
'F':[{'B':3},{'E':2},{'G':1}],
'G': [{'D':1}, {'F':1}]
}

import math

def dijkstras(graph, start):
#Initiate an empty dictionary for path, and one for the vertices in a graph.
    path, remaining_vertices = {}, {}
#Set values of vertices in graph to infinite
    for vertex in graph:
        remaining_vertices[vertex] = math.inf
#The value of the starting point to itself is always 0.
    remaining_vertices[start] = 0

#Loop until the path has access to all the vertices in a graph
while len(path) < len(graph):
    #variables to select the minimum key/value out of the remaining vertices not yet added into the graph
    min_key = math.inf
    min_weight= math.inf

    #Find minimum value
    for vertex, weight in list(remaining_vertices.items()):
        if weight<min_weight:
            min_weight = weight
            min_key = vertex

    """
    For the vertex to be added into the path, check the values of it's neighbors to see if the path going through
    this vertex is shorter than the currently stored value to that neighbor vertex, if so, overwrite.
    Only for neighbor vertexes that are not already in path.

    min(stored_value, current_vertex_weight + edge_weight_to_neighbor_vertex)
    """

    for neighbors in graph[min_key]:
        for edge, edge_weight in list(neighbors.items()):
            if edge not in path:
                remaining_vertices[edge] = min(remaining_vertices[edge], min_weight+edge_weight)

    #Add our selected vertex and its associated weight to our path dictionary
    path[min_key] = min_weight #Add it to our shortest path

    #Remove it from our selectable vertexes for the next path.
    del remaining_vertices[min_key] #Delete it from our remaining vertices

return path

print(dijkstras(g, 'A'))
```

Comment: This should rather be asked on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Paul While you are correct that this question should be on Code Review, it would be better to [pick a bona fide reason](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313266/1157100) for ruling it off-topic on Stack Overflow. (Your preference to see it elsewhere is not good enough a reason.) The real reason is that there is no specific problem to be solved, and hence Too Broad for Stack Overflow.